# Is there a way to set properties of a dashed outline in CSS?

Tags: css, svg

In SVG there are properties you can set to a dashed outline.

```css
.Rectangle_3 {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: visible;
 width: 224px;
 height: 198px;
 left: 10px;
 top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="Rectangle_3">
  <rect fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" stroke="rgba(0,118,255,1)" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-dasharray="1 8" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-miterlimit="4" shape-rendering="auto" id="Rectangle_3" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="224" height="198">
 </rect>
</svg>
```

In CSS outline there is a dashed outline style.

```css
.rectangle1 {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: visible;
 width: 224px;
 height: 198px;
 left: 10px;
 top: 10px;
 outline: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle1">

</div>
```

Is there a way to set the dash array and dash offset in a CSS outline?

[MDN Outline Style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-style)

Comment: No...these properties do not exist. Stroke dash is *not* an **outline** as such. It's "paint" on the path.

Comment: Like Paulie pointed out, there's no properties baked in for it, but you can fake the illusion of the same result pretty well with [background linear gradient](https://codepen.io/danichk/pen/PPRxrR).

Comment: @Paulie_D I couldn't find any either. Would you want to write your comment as an answer?

Comment: @ChrisW. That's pretty slick. Want to write it as an answer?